# Why am I getting so many errors?

Tags: 12.10, error-handling

I have had Ubuntu 12.10 installed for about two hours now. Google Chrome has crashed about fourteen times, I've gotten two 'Ubuntu 12.10 internal error' messages, the Software Center is not working properly, and Ubuntu Tweak has crashed on me at least twice (in three uses of it).

All I did was install Ubuntu 12.10. I did literally nothing else but install a few applications (Skype, Tweak, ccsm, Chrome, Chromium). I haven't changed any important files, and I haven't tweaked anything but some aesthetics.

Can anyone please help me? I don't even know what information might be helpful here, but if you ask for it I will give it.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Was it an Update?

Comment: If you installed from an ISO image or a CD/DVD, get its checksum from the web and compute the checksum for your copy and make sure it's a good copy.  Sometimes downloads and burns complete successfully, but the resulting image/disc still has errors.  If it does, backup your data, get a new image and verify it, then reinstall.  If you did an upgrade, sometimes they don't work as well as a clean install, so you may need to do a clean install.  I don't know of a good way to be sure if this is the problem.

Comment: I have a clean Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 too and it is very up to date. But crashes occurrence is very high (randomly and in average, one per 30 seconds). WHY?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the ISO/IMG file's MD5SUM? I had experienced a "successful" installation of Ubuntu, but every program randomly crashed. I re-installed Ubuntu again and the same thing happened.

It turned out that the ISO file downloaded was missing a few bits, so the MD5SUM did not match.

I downloaded the image again, checked the MD5SUM, and Ubuntu worked without any problems.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstaling Ubuntu Tweak. I've found that some of the third part programs for tweaking Unity cause odd problems (make sure you reset everything to default settings first). I would also suggest checking Ubuntu Tweak's website to see if you have the newest version. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Install additional drivers from the software center if possible and install any needed drivers. If that doesn't help, start chrome from the terminal by typing google-chrome and tell us the output from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it had something to do with the amount of memory I had.

Try @Upper Jack 's answer first, then go ahead with other ones. This is often a problem, even if only a few bytes are off it creates major havoc, if you get my drift.

First off, try installing/using for a day LXDE. 
It's really easy to do, just open up terminal `Ctrl + Alt + T` and enter the command `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-lxde` 
This will simply install the LXDE DE (Desktop Environment) and will allow you to select it on login.

Try doing this and then rebooting. When you log in, select `Lubuntu` from the menu. If this runs fine, then you have a fix! If not, try the following.

Try comparing your computer's specs to the required ones for Ubuntu and see how close they are (memory-wise/video card-wise).
If they are rather close, that could very well be your problem.